# jquery masked input error when using tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm using jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js and there is a bug when i tab the textbox with a masked input

heres my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $default = $('input[type="text"].required');

    $default.live('focus.checkDefault', function() {
        var el = $(this);
        if (el.hasClass('default')) {
            el.removeClass('default').val('');
        }
        if (el.attr('name') === 'landline_number') {
            $(this).mask('(99)(99)999-9999', {placeholder:'_'});
        }
        if (el.attr('name') === 'mobile_number') {
            $(this).mask('(99)999-999-9999', {placeholder:'_'});
        }
        if (el.attr('name') === 'secondary_number') {
            $(this).mask('(99)999-999-9999', {placeholder:'_'});
        }
    });
});
```

when i tab at the textbox landline_number to mobile_number, the landline_number masked input  will be bug.

Comment: What error you are seeing?

Comment: (__)_1_-__1-___1  this is the error when i'm using the tab

Comment: try to use `unmask` before `mask`, because every `focus event` new mask will be added to your textbox: `$(this).unmask().mask(/*your options*/)`

Comment: @Pinal can you please give me a sample code where to put $(this).unmask().mask ?

Comment: Just paste before every mask unmask method...

Comment: @Pinal i just tried it and the error is still the same

Comment: Create jsfiddle please

Comment: @pinal http://jsfiddle.net/hellosze/wsr8z/

Comment: And what is the problem? I pressed tab and all is fine. Mask without `1`. What browser do you use?

Comment: @Pinal just play with the tabs at the textboxes. at some time the bug will appear

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45528/discussion-between-vincent-and-pinal)

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you want to use `focus` event on `.checkDefault` element, if so you can do:

```
 $default.on('focus', '.checkDefault', function() {
```

Comment: it doesn't work and the jquery is destroyed. this is the sample bug.  (qqqq1111__)___-___-___

Comment: i didn't have any error, but the input masked is still buged.
(qqqq1111__)___-- –  this is the sample bug